# changing results from a search to a premade search (php)

Tags: php, twitter

original code was

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "http://www.search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => '#hashtag', 'rpp' => 4));


$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
    $status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
    if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
    $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}


echo "Success! Check your twitter bot for retweets!";
```

this would originally search for a certain keyword and tweet what ever was said about with that hashtag.

I want to change this so it posts what a custom search from https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Aeurogamer%2C%20OR%20from%3Anintendolife%2C%20OR%20from%3Aoutsidexbox&src=typd

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Aeurogamer%2C%20OR%20from%3Anintendolife%2C%20OR%20from%3Aoutsidexbox&src=typd";
$search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => '', 'rpp' => 4));


$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
    $status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
    if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
    $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}


echo "Success! Check your twitter bot for retweets!";
```

I guess I wouldn't need the $search anymore, I would still need the criteria set to only post 4 but how can I work this around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a look at [the docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search), I'm pretty sure you'd do this:

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
// API v1
$twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => 'from:eurogamer OR from:nintendolife OR from:outsidebox', 'rpp' => 4));
/*
// API v1.1 (I think)
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$search = $twitter->get('search/tweets',
                        array('q' => 'from:eurogamer OR from:nintendolife OR from:outsidebox',
                              'count' => 4)
                       );
*/

$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
    $status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
    if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
    $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}

echo "Success! Check your twitter bot for retweets!";
```

(You may have to [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the search query string, I don't know whether the TwitterOAuth library already does that for you.)

Comment: yea that's perfect and the TwitterOAuth library already does that for you. Thank You I over complicated thinking this one

Comment: No probs, you appear to be using the old API version 1 for the search. It might be worth updating your code to use the API version 1.1 instead - I've added what I think the new code would be to my answer.

Comment: yea I checked that over the API 1.1 attempt didn't work. The dev.twitter.com suggestions show

Constructing a Query


If you are not sure how to construct a query for the Search API you can:
1.Run your search on twitter.com/search.
2.Copy the URL. For example: https://twitter.com/#!/search/%40twitterapi
3.Replace https://twitter.com/#!/search/ with https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=. For example: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi

Comment: doing your example brought an error code on line 16 which was the foreach

Comment: original code works just my Oauth file and twittero files were outdated